# How to stop executing waterfall on error in async of node.js?

Tags: node.js, async.js, waterfall

I am using async module with waterfall method.

```
async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            ...
            callback(err);
        },
        function(result, callback) {
            console.log("This function should not be executed");
        }
    ],
    function(err) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
    }
);
```

But the second function always execute. How to prevent it?

Comment: It should not. Make sure that `err` is a truthy value.

Comment: Make sure to always return when calling a callback early, otherwise you will cause multiple callbacks and unpredictable behavior in many cases - advice from here: caolan.github.io/async

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding a `return`

```
async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            ...
            return callback(err); //note return here
        },
        function(result, callback) {
            console.log("This function should not be executed");
        }
    ],
    function(err) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
    }
);
```