# Node.Js - exit out of exec after continuous commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, async.js

I'm executing a few git commands in sequence, in particular, I'm following a git flow model,

e.g. when finishing a feature, I run,

```
git pull
git push -u origin branchname
git pull origin develop
git checkout develop
git merge branchname
git push
```

I run these commands using the `exec` module in node.js and I chain them one after another, like:

```
exec(command1,
     (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if(err != null) {
                  //display an error message
                  return
            } else {
                  exec(command2, (err, stdout, stderr) =>{ ... }
            }

      }
)
```

And so on. The outputs are working correctly and the order is working. However, if one of those commands fail, I am breaking out of the chain.

I know that there is an async library that I could use with the same effect, per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559822/how-to-stop-executing-waterfall-on-error-in-async-of-node-js). However, is this the best possible way to do that without resorting to a third-party library? How have other people done it?

Comment: I think what you are actually looking for is a shell script, not a node module.

Comment: Just use `if (!err)`?

Comment: @Bergi I'm using `if(!err)` and also I'm developing on Electron.

Comment: You haven't shown that in the code you posted. Please [edit] your question and provide your actual code.

Comment: Just updated it! I updated the wording of my question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, is this the best possible way to do that without resorting to a third-party library?

No.

> How have other people done it?

There are three kinds of other solutions:

- just use that library. Being used is its entire purpose.
- reinvent that library. Because then it's not third-party any more, whatever benefits that may have.
- use promises! (And partial application)

  ```
  function makeExec(command) {
      return function(/* ignore results */) {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              child_process.exec(command, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                  if (err != null) reject(Object.assign(err, {stderr}));
                  else resolve(stdout);
              });
          });
      });
  }
  Promise.resolve()
  .then(makeExec("git pull"))
  .then(makeExec("git push -u origin branchname"))
  .then(makeExec("git pull origin develop"))
  .then(makeExec("git checkout develop"))
  .then(makeExec("git merge branchname"))
  .then(makeExec("git push"))
  .catch(function(err) {
      //display an error message
  })
  ```

Comment: I'm going to try going the route of the stackoverflow answer I linked in my question. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Using `async` you can do this with [`eachSeries`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries):

```
var commands = [
  'git pull',
  'git checkout',
  '...'
];

eachSeries(commands, (command, cb) => {
  exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    cb(err);
  });
});
```

It's generally better to find a library that does this than to have to wrangle your own solution by hand.